# Not sure why 1 printf statement prints twice

Tags: c

**UPDATE**

I thought this code block was giving me an error printing a printf statement out twice, but I commented out everything in my code BESIDES this and it worked just fine! What seems to be the issue then is the work I am doing with process IDs. 
Here is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pid_t pid, pid1;
int n;
int temp;
int stop = 1;

if (argc == 1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ./a.out <starting value>\n");

    return -1;
}

n = atoi(argv[1]);

pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) { /* error occurred */
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
    return 1;
}

else if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
    pid1 = getpid();
    printf("child: pid = %d\n", pid);
    printf("child: pid1 = %d\n", pid1);
}

else { /* parent process */
    pid1 = getpid();
    printf("parent: pid = %d\n", pid);
    printf("parent: pid1 = %d\n", pid1);
    wait(NULL);
}
while (n!=1) {  
    if (n%2 == 0) {
        printf("%d, ", n);
        temp = (n/2);
        n = temp;
    }else {
        printf("%d, ", n);
        temp = (3*n+1); 
        n = temp;
    }
}
printf("1\n");
return 0;
```

}

The output I'm expecting is something like:

```
parent: pid = 1444
parent: pid1 = 1443
child: pid = 0
child: pid = 1444
8, 4, 2, 1
```

But instead I get this Output:

```
parent: pid = 1444
parent: pid1 = 1443
child: pid = 0
child: pid = 1444
8, 4, 2, 1
8, 4, 2, 1
```

Might a child a parent process be printing out the sequence a second time?

Comment: I tried the code you're showing and it, as I expected, prints the output once. So what you show doesn't have the described problem. However, there's something you're not showing since I don't see the whole `main` program.

Comment: Can you show us the *full* code file? (It should start with a `#include`, include `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or similar, etc.) It might also help to see how you're running the file.

Comment: same here, I compiled your code and I only got one line. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well... since the second time the sequence prints it's on a new line, we can pretty safely assume it's nothing to do with your `while` loop. Three pretty likely possibilities : the shown subroutine is executed twice, you're accidentally running the program twice at a command line, or the program that you're printing to is bugged.

Comment: My vote is for "the program that you're printing to is bugged". Are you running this in a command line or in your IDE?

Comment: Don't use `atoi` because it does a terrible job handling errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, once the parent process has `wait()`ed on the child process, it continues down the code path and prints the sequence.

What you want is:

```
// ....
else if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
    pid1 = getpid();
    printf("child: pid = %d\n", pid);
    printf("child: pid1 = %d\n", pid1);

    while (n!=1) {  
        if (n%2 == 0) {
            printf("%d, ", n);
            temp = (n/2);
            n = temp;
        }else {
            printf("%d, ", n);
            temp = (3*n+1); 
            n = temp;
        }
    }
} else { /* parent process */
    pid1 = getpid();
    printf("parent: pid = %d\n", pid);
    printf("parent: pid1 = %d\n", pid1);
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After

```
 wait(NULL);
```

You need an exit/return. The parent has done its job of bringing up the child and is done